# `INSERT` is only inserting a single row

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I've been happily using SequelPro in place of phpMyAdmin to access my local database.

I've inserted hundreds of rows into some tables without a glitch.

Now I can't insert more than a single row into any table - even using the same INSERT script I previously used successfully. I CAN use the same script to insert multiple rows via phpMyAdmin, however. Via SequelPro only the last row is entered:

```
insert into country (country_desc, country_pop) values ('Monaco', NULL);
insert into country (country_desc, country_pop) values ('Mongolia', NULL);
insert into country (country_desc, country_pop) values ('Montenegro', NULL);
insert into country (country_desc, country_pop) values ('Montserrat', NULL);
```

...though i think my tests have shown it isn't the script at fault. (The country table has an auto_increment column, country_id, which is working fine for the single row inserted.)

I've tried restarting Sequel Pro and my local server MAMP but no joy. It feels like I've changed a setting in Sequel Pro unwittingly.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Please don't use fake pseudo-tags in titles. They are inconsistent, unindexable etc. SO already has a tags system. :)

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you reproduce this problem. Buttons pressed, keys pressed, SQL schema etc.

Comment: What's the data type of the auto_inc column?

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing the "run current query" action (i.e. the query under the caret), rather than "run all queries" action? They have different [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Keyboard_Shortcuts).